# TypeError in web3 v1.0.0

Tags: web3js

I am checking in web3 if it is listening to a port using

```
var web3 = new Web3();
if(web3.setProvider(new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('ws://localhost:8545')))){
    web3.eth.net.isListening()
    .then(() => console.log('is connected'))
    .catch(e => console.log('Wow. Something went wrong'));
}
```

but it giving type error:

> TypeError: this.provider[(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)] is not a function

Answer (score 2):

this line is wrong

```
web3.setProvider(new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('ws://localhost:8545')))
```

it should be

```
web3.setProvider(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('ws://localhost:8545'))
```

or shortly, you can also do

```
web3.setProvider('ws://localhost:8545')
```

or even better, when you create the instance

```
var web3 = new Web3('ws://localhost:8545');
```